# Creating a binary tree from a binary sequence in python

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to binary create a tree from a binary sequence like "100101"
then i want the tree to be created like this. (Basically 1 means go to the right and 0 means go to the left)

```
                                <Root node>
                                    |
                                    1
                                   /
                                  0
                                 /
                                0
                                 \
                                  1
                                 /
                                0
                                 \
                                  1
```

so i did it here is the code:
where the value would be the string sequence (ex value = "1001")

```
def _inserto(root,value):
    for i in value:
        if root == None:
            root = BSTNode(i)
            current = root
        elif i == "1":
            if current.right is not None:
                current.right = BSTNode(i)
                current = current.right
            else:
                current.right = BSTNode(i)
                current = current.right
        elif i == "0":
            if (current.left is not None):
                current.left = BSTNode(i)
                current = current.left
            else:
                current.left =BSTNode(i)
                current = current.left
    return root
```

Now the problem is that if i want to input another sequence like "01", the tree should look like this

```
                            <Root Node>
                                |
                                1
                               /
                              0
                             / \
                            0   1
                             \
                              1
                             /
                            0
                             \
                              1
```

, but i am really having a hard time, since my function is going to over-write the old tree.

Comment: What part of this, *exactly* is problematic? You can keep an external reference to the last node in python just as well. You know python has classes and objects too?

Comment: "Basically 1 means go to the right and 0 means go to the left" Err... from your diagram it seems that 1 means go left. Is your diagram wrong, or am I reading it the wrong way?

Comment: @MarkByers I'm sharing your "err..." between the diagram and the code for `_insert` - Start with an intial root of 1, next is 0 < 1 so it goes left, but then 0 is not < 0, so it should go right (but is shown as going left)... I'm hoping the OP can clarify which of the three possible results is actually desired.

Comment: i am assuming we start with a initial empty tree, and when i insert a value, i look at it, if its a 0, it goes to the left and if its a one it goes to the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the code dealing with an existing node. If it is present, the code overwrites it with a new BSTNode, losing all the existing nodes under it. What you need is something like:

```
    elif i == "1":
        if current.right is None:
            current.right = BSTNode(i)
        current = current.right
    elif i == "0":
        if root.left is None:
            current.left = BSTNode(i)
        current = current.left
```

This will only allocate a node if there is not one already present, and then set current to this new node.